# visual basic mdi arrangement isn't operate

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I using visual studio 2010 and .NET Framework version is 4.6 . 
I want to arrange mdi child form. For example, horizontal, vertical, cascade..
So I searched information and I wrote the code but was not operate. Help me..

And I used MenuStrip in mdi form and my code is

```
Private Sub Windows_DropDownItemClicked(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs) Handles Windows.DropDownItemClicked
    Dim sMenuItem As String

    sMenuItem = e.ClickedItem.Name

    If sMenuItem = "CascadeMenuItem" Then
        Me.LayoutMdi(System.Windows.Forms.MdiLayout.Cascade)
    ElseIf sMenuItem = "HorizontalMenuItem" Then
        Me.LayoutMdi(System.Windows.Forms.MdiLayout.TileHorizontal)
    ElseIf sMenuItem = "VerticalMenuItem" Then
        Me.LayoutMdi(System.Windows.Forms.MdiLayout.TileVertical)
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

I would compare against the actual control, instead of using their names:

```
Private Sub Windows_DropDownItemClicked(sender As Object, e As ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs) Handles Windows.DropDownItemClicked
    If e.ClickedItem Is CascadeMenuItem Then
        Me.LayoutMdi(MdiLayout.Cascade)
    ElseIf e.ClickedItem Is HorizontalMenuItem Then
        Me.LayoutMdi(MdiLayout.TileHorizontal)
    ElseIf e.ClickedItem Is VerticalMenuItem Then
        Me.LayoutMdi(MdiLayout.TileVertical)
    End If
End Sub
```

Other than that, not sure what else could be wrong.  Can you show a screenshot of your form?